# How to make ZoneOffset UTC return "+00:00" instead of "Z"

Tags: java, timezone-offset

Is there any built-in method in java to return `"+00:00"` for `ZoneOffset` UTC? The `getId()` method only return `"Z"`.

My current approach is manual change it to `"+00:00"` if the result is `"Z"`

```
public static String getSystemTimeOffset() {
    String id = ZoneOffset.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(Instant.now()).getId();
    return "Z".equals(id) ? "+00:00" : id;
}
```

Comment: No, it follows ISO-8601 standards

Comment: @nitnamby `+00:00` is also an option according to ISO 8601. It contains quite many freedoms, also sometimes more than the `java.time` API can handle (I believe it *parses* `+00:00` just fine).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
private static DateTimeFormatter offsetFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("xxx");

public static String getSystemTimeOffset() {
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());
    return offsetFormatter.format(offset);
}
```

It turns out that a `ZoneOffset` can be formatted just like a date-time object can (except there is no `ZoneOffset.format` method, so we need to use the `DateTimeFormatter.format` method and pass the zone offset). So it’s a matter of reading the documentation of `DateTimeFormatter`. There are plenty of format pattern letters that you can use for formatting an offset: `O`, `X`, `x` and `Z`. And for each it makes a difference how many we put in the format. Uppercase `X` will give you the `Z` that you don’t want, so we can skip that. The examples seem to indicate that we can use lowercase `x` or uppercase `Z` here. For `x`: “Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'.” Bingo.

Link: [`DateTimeFormatter` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)